# Wifi Enabling broadcast coming late

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, wifimanager

I've got a widget that I'm trying to use to enable/disable wifi, as well as display some additional info. I want to show a transitional hourglass icon while Wifi is enabling/disabling, so I'm listening for the android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED intent.

When that intent is caught I'm calling the widget's onUpdate function, and in that I have this block of code for changing the image displayed:

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("com.nickavv.cleanwidgets", R.layout.wifi_toggle_layout_large);

supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
wifiState = wifiMan.getWifiState();

if(wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
    //Show enabled image
} else if(wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED){
    //Show disabled image
} else {
    //Show hourglass
}
```

And here's my code for intercepting clicks and wifi state changes:

```
@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) { 
        if(wifiState != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING || wifiState != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING) {
            switchToggle(context);
        }
    }
    AppWidgetManager myAWM = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, WifiWidgetLarge.class);
    onUpdate(context, myAWM, myAWM.getAppWidgetIds(cn));
}
```

This works fine on the smaller widget, which is just a toggle switch, but on the larger widget the exact same code doesn't produce the correct results. It shows the hourglass while disabling, but not while enabling. It seems that the intent is being received too late to display anything, as debug logs show that it is eventually being received. It's just not coming in with WIFI_STATE_ENABLING until immediately before the state changes to WIFI_STATE_ENABLED.

Most baffling of all, the widget works fine on my tablet, and my roommate's phone, just not on my phone. However, I don't want to release it until I can be more sure of its performance. Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of the OS are on all those devices you mentioned?

Comment: Gingerbread on my phone, and my roommate's. Ice Cream Sandwich on my tablet

Comment: I've now tested it on my other roommate's Asus Transformer running Ice Cream Sandwich (works as expected), and my yet other roommate's Acer A500 running Honeycomb (works as expected). What's so different about my phone?

Comment: your widget enables your wifi, right? then why is important to able to see the hourglass, if the wifi already enabled?

Answer (score -1):

May be there were more tuning after Gingerbread version. What you could do now is check for the android version and if its a GB, you would need to do some hack.

You could check for WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and get the previous/next states using

EXTRA_WIFI_STATE
EXTRA_PREVIOUS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: I'm about to resort to a hack of some kind, it just bothers me that the same code on the same phone works on my other Wifi widget but not this one